# Фильтр запроса из БД

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

Приходит запрос получить все товары, соответствующие фильтрам 14 и 15. Я делаю запрос в базу данных и мне выдаёт такой список. Теперь как реализовать удаление товара с id 11 из списка (соответствие лишь по одному фильтру), оставив 10, и потом убрать дублирование товаров?

```
from FilterGoodCountEntity 
where good.category.id=10 
  and (filter.id=14 or filter.id=15)
```

Получаем такой список:

```
id фильтра / id товара
——————————————————————
    14    /    11
    14    /    10
    15    /    10
——————————————————————
```

P.S.: многие к одному затея не очень, да, но это не мои глюки.

Comment: а в Вашей `FilterGoodCountEntity` есть поле которое отвечает за энтити фильтра?

Comment: `GROUP BY id_товара HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT id_фильтра) = 2`